# Capturing data from Data Layer Variable object

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a data layer object that I'm trying to retrieve data from, but I don't have any luck. Currently, it's capturing the entire array under the ecommerce variable as an object. However, I can't retrieve any of the data items from that object into a separate variable.

[Here is the image from Google Tag Assistant of what is being captured under the ecommerce variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtKDM.png)

[This is the GTM setup for the ecommerce variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVQd.png)

[I'm trying to capture state using this configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNcyJ.png)

[The userid variable is picking up, but using the exact same setup, state isnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRtLx.png)

[The array in console looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDVNh.png)

Here is the

```
     (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
     if (window.location.href.indexOf("thank-you") > -1)
     {j.defer=true;} else {j.async=true;} 
     j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-******');
```

**Update:**

I was able to get ecommerce.state, ecommerce.currency, ecommerce.zipcode, and ecommerce.emailAddress. However, when I try to get petDetails values, I get nothing. So for example, I'm trying to get petid, I'm using ecommerce.petDetails.petid, but no values are populating for any of the petDetails fields.

[I've added the array from the console with all the fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtn5A.png)

Comment: Can you show some examples of your code, or otherwise tell us about what you tried?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the original post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

So you've pushed everything into a data layer object called "ecommerce"

So to access the various values under "ecommerce" you just have to use

"ecommerce.state" or "ecommerce.userid"

"userid" is available without you doing the above us probably because "userid" actually exists outside of the "ecommerce" object.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to get ecommerce.state, ecommerce.currency, ecommerce.zipcode, and ecommerce.emailAddress.

However, when I try to get petDetails values, I get nothing.

So for example, I'm trying to get petid, I'm using ecommerce.petDetails.petid, but no values are populating for petDetails.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I was able to answer my own question. I was able to get the nested array using this:

ecommerce.petDetails.0.petid